# Compatibility between EPL and LGPL

Tags: license-compatibility, lgpl, epl

I'm using LGPL binaries, as well as EPL binaries for my open source project. Is this OK? And if yes, does that mean I should license my project under LGPL?

The binaries are being used as dependencies for the project i.e. I'm just using them as-is without making changes to them.

Comment: You're going to need to add more details for this to be sensibly answered. How are you using said binaries?

Comment: OK, added more details. Do tell me more clarification is necessary.

Comment: Have you modified the sources or the binaries of the other projects?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the sources of the binaries.

Comment: I clicked the wrong bounty option, cause I'm tired. That's okay, it doesn't really make a difference :)

Comment: @cat Nice of you to add the bounty. However, I think the main reason why there aren't any answers here is primarily due to the lack of information (which is probably our fault as well for not asking questions...). Do you share the same situation here? I'm debating writing a canonical answer here when I find the time.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yes, at least a little bit -- I want to make a project in the Clojure programming language, which is licensed with the EPL, and which links to Apache 2.0 code, but I want *my* code (which obviously has to link with the previously mentioned code) to be GPL v3. GPL3 and EPL are not compatible :( and 2/3-claws BSD or Apache seem farther from the GPL3 than LGPL, which is still (or seems to be, but I cannot figure out for sure) compatible with the EPL.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I was debating writing my own question, or spending rep on a bounty, and I decided to take the lazy route. I'll craft a question presenting my findings and why they confuse me if this one isn't fruitful.

Comment: @Zizouz212 The difference of opinion here is really helpful (not): [EPL (Eclipse Public License), GPL (GNU Public License)/LGPL (Lesser GPL) and license exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5393873/4532996)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using LGPL binaries, as well as EPL binaries for my open source project. Is this OK?

Yes.

> And if yes, does that mean I should license my project under LGPL? The binaries are being used as dependencies for the project i.e. I'm just using them as-is without making changes to them.

No: this is common for Java-based project to depend and re-use as-is pre-built packages (typically provisioned through Maven) that are under the EPL or the LGPL. The EPL or LGPL does not extend to your own code in this case.

And if you redistribute these dependencies, as long as you are respecting the terms of the licenses of these deps, this typically does not impact the license you can use in your own code.

The simple way to respect the terms would be to do this for each dep:

- include all licenses and notices (or create them if they are missing), include some doc to give credit and display these licenses and notices.
- provide the corresponding source code for these deps

This may be more than needed in some cases (for instance unmodified redistribution of EPL-licensed code does not require exactly source code redistribution) but this is simple and easier to apply (and automate) and ensure a decent compliance across the board.

You could also apply the same approach to other packages.

Comment: What do you mean by "redistribute these dependencies"?

Comment: @peco you have two ways to use dependent libraries in Java assuming you are using Maven and a typical approach: 1. You distribute only your own code with a pom and instructions to run Maven or ivy or else to fetch the dependencies remotely at install time. 2. You distribute your own code and the dependent jars bundled together